# java generic method return type

Tags: java, oop, generics, arraylist

In the code below, the method "bla()" returns ArrayList of Object instead of String, how come?

```
public class MyClass<T>{   
        public ArrayList<String> bla(){
            return new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        public static void foo(){
           new MyClass().bla().add([here auto complete says "Object" not "String"])
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I paste that code into IntelliJ it states that that the method 'add' takes a String

Comment: edit: public class MyClass<T>
now it takes Object...

Comment: That is odd, and even odder, if you change the line to `new MyClass<>().bla().add();` it takes String as the arg

Comment: Glad to have helped, but I want to know why it behaves this way!

Comment: pretty odd truly.. must be for some reason  I am not familiar with, maybe someone will know and tell us

Comment: Closed as a duplicate, but it doesn't seem the linked answer addresses this scenario; if T was being passed down as the type of the ArrayList created by bla() the linked answer would cover this, as it is it doesn't I think

Comment: I get String too.  Sounds like a bug in your editor.  What IDE are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't parameterized this new instance creation expression

```
new MyClass()
```

The resulting value is of the raw type `MyClass`. The [Java Language Specification states](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8)

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or
>   non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type `C` that is not inherited from its
>   superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to
>   the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to `C`.

That is

```
public ArrayList<String> bla(){
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

is now viewed as

```
public ArrayList bla() {
    return new ArrayList<String>();
}
```

The return type is itself the raw type `ArrayList` and the type of its `add` method also becomes the raw type of its erasure, ie. `Object` from generic variable `T`.

Obviously, you can still add a `String` to a method that expects an `Object`, but type safety is broken for anyone that has a properly parameterized view of the `MyClass` instance.

Read:

- [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)